# DotTrace plugin to TeamCity - process filter is not excluding nunit3-console.exe

Tags: teamcity, dottrace

I'd like to ask for some help about setting up the DotTrace plugin for one of our TeamCity builds - so far I've followed the instructions here, and got a build that sometimes works:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/02/16/performance-profiling-in-continuous-integration-an-updated-dottrace-plugin-to-teamcity/

However, this is sometimes failing because the build produces two snapshots (**snapshot.dtp** and **snapshot-2.dtp**).

After much trial-and-error I've found out that sometimes the reason this fails is because my tests sometimes appear in the first .dtp file (which is the one used by DotTrace's Reporter.exe), and sometimes in the second file.

The other .dtp file appears to be associated with the nunit3-console.exe program, and so should be excluded, since I've added this program to "Process Filters" in the TeamCity build setup:

`*nunit3-console.exe`

(I've tried every combination here, including entering the fully qualified file path)

This has the effect of adding the following line to the dotTrace.project.xml file when the profiler is run:

`<ProcessNameFilter>*nunit3-console.exe</ProcessNameFilter>`

My understanding is that this should stop the named process from being profiled (so that the extra .dtp file isn't produced. However when the build is running, I see the following lines in the log file:

> [16:01:04][Step 12/14] dotTrace Console Profiler 2018.3.2 build 777.0.20190124.112417. Copyright (C) 2019 JetBrains s.r.o.
>
> [16:01:10][Step 12/14] Profiling in progress...
>
> [16:01:10][Step 12/14] Executable='[file path]\nunit3-console.exe' (non-child) is being passed for filtering
>
> [16:01:10][Step 12/14] Passed filter executable='[file path]\nunit3-console.exe'

This is showing that the nunit3-console.exe is not being excluded, as the filter would suggest.

The closest advice I can find is here, which appears to suggest what I'm doing, but is only for NUnit 2:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__Profiling_Unit_Tests.html

Does anyone know of a way to ensure nunit3-console.exe is excluded, so that it does not produce a snapshot file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin produces several snapshots by design and generates report based on all snapshots so filtering is not needed here.

I've created the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-59310)

Comment: Thank you Nikolay - the plugin seems to consistently use only snapshot.dtp, and never any of the others - perhaps you're right that the design is for the plugin to use all snapshot files. I'll add a comment to the issue to reflect this

Comment: Issue was fixed. @KevinC thank you for paying attention to this problem.